# The cache in redis can not be clear automatic when Redisson restart

Tags: redis, redisson

I have set the ttl and idleTime for cache, the cache can be remove when the app is running, however when I restart app the EvictionScheduler may not work for cache, the cache can not be clear when ttl approach.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rskyy.png)

```java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedissonClient redissonClient) throws IOException {
    Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String, CacheConfig>();
    config.put(CacheNames.XinLianService_getAllAgentData, new CacheConfig(60 * 1000, 60 * 1000));
    config.put(CacheNames.XinlianRoleService_getById, new CacheConfig(2 * 60 * 1000, 60 * 1000));
    return new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient, config);
}
```